# Sync request/response messaging using azure functions and azure service bus

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

So far I was able to develop following sync request response pattern using console app and azure service bus; I'm trying to replace Console apps with azure functions here;

To get a sync response, server after sending request msg with a SessionId, it binds to the response queue to receive messages for that session;
[image]

I haven't been able to replace console apps with azure function and I'm not sure if it's doable?

The issue comes down to azure function being able to work (Bind & Trigger) with two different queues, one sending messages (bind) to and then registering and listening to the other queue for specific session (trigger).

and if it's doable what are potential problems/cost issues using this sync request/response with azure functions?

Thanks

Comment: Azure Service Bus is a messaging service, and it's **asynchronous** by design. What you've got is not a synchronous implementation. It's still async. A sync implementation is a request/response. What you have is a request/reply. It would be nice to understand what you are trying to build w/o diving into the implementation details first and then see if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Update
I was able to implement this request/response pattern with azure funcs.

here are some good articles

https://www.middleway.eu/building-synchronous-apis-on-an-asynchronous-event-bus-using-azure-service-bus/

https://jinalkumarpatel.hashnode.dev/request-response-using-azure-service-bus